# Codeigniter - Form validation converting post variables from Array to "Array" string

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am building an HTML form with a set of checkboxes for selecting multiple categories using this format:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" />
```

So, when I post and `print_r($_POST)` to view the variable and values I get:

```
Array
(
    [27] => on
    [28] => on
    [29] => on
)
```

Once I run `$this->form_validation->run();` the categories array becomes "Array" as a string.  I believe I have narrowed it down to "prep_for_form" function in the system/libraries/Form_validation.php file, but it seems like the recursive function is working correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it the same when you do `print_r($this->input->post)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  When using the `$this->form_validation->set_rules()` method, in the validation rules (third parameter) I set it to `trim|required`. I guess the trim function treats the actual Array like a string "Array" and trims the word. I simply removed the "trim" rule from my validation rules. e.g.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'categories', 'trim|required');

// when parsing an array (set of checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.) 
// - remove the "trim" validation
$this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'categories', 'required');
```

I hope others find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

That solution did not work for me, but there is a fix listed here that did: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/156497/